# how to use multiprocessing for 1000 simulations

Tags: python, multiprocessing

```
def array_generator(total_array,i):
    rd_array = np.random.rand(18,100)
    total_array[i] = rd_array
    return total_array[i]
```

Now I want to do 1000 simulation and store into total_array
How do I use multiprocessing to generate 1000 simulation?

Thank you so much:)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you can use concurrent.futures module by running this function 1000 times.

https://coderzcolumn.com/tutorials/python/concurrent-futures

The above tutorial has a simple example that you can try to imitate.